# When will "Spring for GraphQL" be integrated in "Spring Boot 3"?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-graphql

I know that *Spring Boot 2.7* has an integration with *Spring for GraphQL 1.0*. However, I cannot find any information at which milestone of *Spring Boot 3* the integration with GraphQL is scheduled. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concrete, official plan right now but our intent is to have something out in time for Spring Boot 3.0. Spring for GraphQL just got out, so we're missing critical feedback to better understand the community.

Since Spring Boot 3.0 is a major version, most projects are also releasing major versions. This might be a bit too soon for Spring for GraphQL and we could consider a 1.1.0 with a limited amount of new features and target a 2.0 later in the 3.x line.

The situation is unusual, but as always the team is listening to the community. When it's official, the plan will materialize [as a new milestone](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/milestones) and/or in [a blog post](https://spring.io/blog/).

Update: [there is now a scheduled 1.1.0 version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/milestone/14) to be released in time for Spring Boot 3.0